# How to specify a non default type when calling a FFmpeg library using ctypes

Tags: python, ffmpeg, ctypes

I am calling an FFMPEG library called avformat_alloc_context() that returns a pointer to type AVFormatContext.  The structure AVFormatContext is defined in the avformat library.

Obviously; this is not one ctypes default types and results in an error when I try to pass a reference to it to another ffmpeg library further down in my code.

Is there a way to add in the the classes defined inside of the library ?  I read through what documentation I could find online and was not able to find a good answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first of all translate the `AVFormatContext` struct into a ctypes declaration. You do this by [deriving from the `Structure` class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#structures-and-unions).

Then you need to specify that the `avformat_alloc_context` function returns a pointer to that struct. You assign `restype` to do so:

```
avformat_alloc_context.restype = POINTER(AVFormatContext)
```

Then you can call the function like this:

```
contextPtr = avformat_alloc_context()
```

To get at the contents of the pointer, read the `contents` attribute:

```
context = contextPtr.contents
```

And don't forget to call `avformat_free_context()` when you have finished with the pointer.

This information is all covered in more detail in the ctypes [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

Comment: Okay;  I see what I was doing wrong. I found the  contextPtr = avformat_alloc_context() and the context = contextPtr.contents and it gave me an error message . I will read up on driving the structure class  Thanks for supplying the top line.  thanks

Comment: I can't help if you don't say what the error message is. Anyway, this points you in the right way.

Comment: I just misunderstood something that I read that gave me the impression that all I had to specify was that return value from the av_format_context() call was a pointer and did not need to define the FFMPEG AvFormatContext structure like you mentioned.

Comment: So long as you don't need to access the struct then you can do that. Set `restype` to be `c_void_p`.

Comment: success. I was able to correct my logic errors  when I had earlier tried the c_void_p approach with your example. the c_void_p method seems to work fine for now. Like you said; if I do need access to the data in the AVFormatContext strcuture in the future.  I will have to define it.